# Java list of file not getting sorted using Comparator

Tags: java, file, sorting, comparator, comparable

I have a list of file that contains the some files.
`List<File> filesToProcess = new ArrayList();`

The elements of this list are :

```
abc20190101.txt
abc20190103.txt
abc20190105.txt
abc20190102.txt
abc20190104.txt
```

So I want to sort it using the file names:
I wrote the following piece of code:

```
Collections.sort(filesToProcess, new Comparator<File>() {
   @Override
   public int compare(File file1, File file2) {
      return file1.getName().compareTo(file2.getName())>0 ? 1 : 0;
   }
});
```

But this does not seem to work.

Infact when printed to console I get the same order in which the list was created.
Could someone please help.

Comment: Your comparator is broken. It never returns a negative. Just return `file1.getName().compareTo(file2.getName())` directly. Or if you're using Java 8+: `filesToProcess.sort(Comparator.comparing(File::getName));`

Comment: just return the compareTo() result and not do a ternary on it

Comment: Ohh thanks people..it was a noobie mistake :P

Comment: For reference: [the documentation of `Comparator::compareTo(T o1, T o1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,T)) states that if `o1` is bigger/equal/smaller as `o2`, then  something `> 0`/`0`/something `< 0` should be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  I created a List of files from the supplied names.

```java
      String[] filenames = {
            "abc20190101.txt", "abc20190103.txt", "abc20190105.txt",
            "abc20190102.txt", "abc20190104.txt"
      };

      List<File> filesToProcess =
            Arrays.stream(filenames).map(File::new).collect(
                  Collectors.toList());

      Collections.sort(filesToProcess, new Comparator<File>() {
         @Override
         public int compare(File file1, File file2) {
            // just use compareTo here since String implements Comparable<String>
            return file1.getName().compareTo(file2.getName());
         }
      });

      filesToProcess.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you explained what you changed, and why.  Merely writing someone’s code for them is not especially useful, particularly for future readers of this question.